# Google play application title

Tags: android, google-play, symbols

Can anyone tell me how to add trademark stamp in application title when publishing app in Google play store. I tried it with "sup" tags but it doesn't work. I want my title to look like DAMIR<sup>TM</sup>. Check FlipShare on play store for example. I apologize for my stupid question but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for this: ™

It's a single character and I suppose if you copy/paste it(or type alt+0153), it should work ;)

Edit:

You could also try using the html codes "&#8482"; or "&trade"; (without the double quotes of course).